# how to bring up sensors in a stand alone Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello!
I am starting a stand alone gazebo and loading a .world from a cpp file with :

```
    gazebo::setupServer();
    // Load a world
    gazebo::physics::WorldPtr world = gazebo::loadWorld(
                "worlds/pepper_base.world");
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
{
   gazebo::runWorld(world, 1);
}
```

This world include a robot model containing an hokuyo laser :
pepper_model.sdf :

```
 <include>
      <uri>model://hokuyo</uri>
      <pose>0.0562 0 -0.303 0 -0.0175 0</pose>
    </include>
    <joint name="hokuyo_joint" type="revolute">
      <child>hokuyo::link</child>
      <parent>Tibia</parent>
      <axis>
        <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
        <limit>
          <upper>0</upper>
          <lower>0</lower>
        </limit>
      </axis>
    </joint>
```

When I am importing this model from the GUI gazebo, no problem, I can listen the laser topic with :

```
gz topic -e /gazebo/default/virtual_pepper/hokuyo/link/laser/scan
```

But when launching my cpp program ( without any gazebo launched, except the server written above ), there is no data comming from the laser.

I tried several function from the gazebo API as :

```
gazebo::sensors::SensorManager *mgr = gazebo::sensors::SensorManager::Instance();
gazebo::sensors::Sensor_V vect_sensor = mgr->GetSensors();
```

=> to init() the captors "by hand" but vect_sensor is always empty

whereas :

```
 gazebo::physics::LinkPtr tibia= pepper->GetLink("Tibia");
 nom=tibia->GetSensorName(0);
```

give me the name of my sensor

What I am missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9491/how-to-bring-up-sensors-in-a-stand-alone-gazebo/) by [scarlett](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1300/scarlett/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

By searching into this file in Gazebo lib :

[server.cc](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/1bb94ce8aaac99ed54c7b166436d67c299cc7d42/gazebo/Server.cc?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#Server.cc-464)

I had the idea to add few lines in my code to take care of sensors :

```
    gazebo::setupServer();
    gazebo::physics::WorldPtr world = gazebo::loadWorld(
                "worlds/pepper_base.world");

    // Make sure the sensors are updated once before running the world.
    // This makes sure plugins get loaded properly.
    gazebo::sensors::run_once(true);
    gazebo::sensors::run_threads();

 for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    {
        gazebo::runWorld(world, 1);
        gazebo::sensors::run_once();
        gazebo::common::Time::MSleep(1);
    }
```

Now it is working fine

---

Originally posted by [scarlett](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1300/scarlett/) with karma: 11 on 2015-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1